# The Google Directions API 'access Denied'

Tags: ios, google-directions-api

can some one guide me how to make use of The Google Directions API by providing latitude and longitude values, I tried doing it but in response it says 'access denied'.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?origin=53.2323832,24.33333,destination=40.33223,20.33333

This is what I tried.

Comment: I don't get access denied, I get a 404 error.

Comment: To use Directions API from Google, you need an API key from your google Account. https://developers.google.com/maps/signup

Comment: If you are getting 404 then your URL is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is wrong. Try this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=53.2323832,24.33333&destination=40.33223,20.33333&sensor=false
```

If you are using Three20, you can also use the [extThree20Google extension.](https://github.com/RIKSOF/three20/tree/development)